# Save data frame to Oracle table

Tags: r

I manage to save first csv to Oracle but when i tried for multiple using loop, its not successful.

```
path = paste("//path_name/")
File = file.info(list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, pattern="xxx"
                                 ,full.names = TRUE))
File = File[with(File, order(as.POSIXct(ctime), decreasing = TRUE)),]
files = rownames(File)
files

for (i in 1:80) {
file_Location <- files[i]
file_Location

file_Final <- read.csv(file_Location)

con1 <- odbcConnect("SQL_Query", uid = "uid", pwd = "pwd")
sqlSave(con1, file_Final, table = "table_name", rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
}
```

error: Error in sqlSave(con1, file_Final, table = "table_name", rownames = FALSE,  :
unable to append to table ‘table_name’

Comment: You read into `file_Final` but try to upload `GPIB_Final`, looks like a typo. If that is not the real culprit, please [edit] and correct the typo in your code above (so that it better matches what you are doing in reality) and please add why you say it is not successful ... does it emit warnings or errors?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Also, your `for ` block has an opening bracket { but not closing }

Comment: typo corrected. error attached.